# form value is not inserted to the database using reacts Js in Fire database

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

```
import React from 'react'
import {Form, Col, Row, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import  {useState} from 'react'


export default function Contact() {
    const [data, setData]=useState({
        name:"Dilshad",
        email:"hjhjas@gmail.com"
    });
    let name, value;
    const postdata = (event)=>{
      name=event.target.value;
      value=event.target.name;
      setData({...data, [name]:value});
    }
  
    const submit=(e)=>{
      e.preventDefault();
      const{name, email}=data;
      if(name){
      const res=fetch('https://react-a278e-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com//userrecord.JSON',
      {
          method:'POST',
          headers:{
              "Content-Type":"application/json"
          },
          body:JSON.stringify({
             name,
             email
          }),

      }
      
      
      );
      if(res){
          setData({
              name:"",
              email:""
          })

          alert("Data save in to database");
      }
    }
      else
      {
          alert("please fill the data");
      }
      
    }

    return (
        <div className='container'>   
        <br/>
        <Form method='POST'>
         <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="formName">
                <Col sm="10">
                <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Name:" name='name'  value={data.name} onChange={postdata}/>
                </Col>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="form-email">
                <Col sm="10">
                <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Email" name='email' value={data.email} onChange={postdata} />
                </Col>
            </Form.Group>
            <Button className='btn-sumit'  variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={submit}>
            Submit
        </Button>
       </Form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have double slash in the endpoint URL. Just before `userrecord.JSON`. Also can you try using lowercase `json`.